# YugaByteDB tablet implementation

Tags: yugabytedb

Reading this doc: *https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/architecture/core-functions/write-path/*

Question 1: Can I think a node in yugabytedb is a machine with IP/port? Or a node can be multiple machines?

Question 2: Can I think a tablet as a service running in Linux that handles read/write for the given shard? How many tablets one machine can hold?

Thanks!

Comment: Q1: a node in the link is a machine. 
However, a YugabyteDB cluster typically consists of multiple nodes working together. With a replication factor set to 3 (which is the standard deployment), 3 nodes are needed at a minimum.
Q2: If a database is colocated and the object is colocated, it is stored in a tablet that stores all the colocated objects for that database. A non-colocated object consists of one or more tablets.
A tablet contains replication factor replicas (typically 3), and has one leader and two followers. Writes are performed on all, reads are performed on the leader.

Comment: Because a tablet can be 1 replica, 3 replicas or 5 or 7, the number of tablets is not the best number. 
However, like for every database, the correct answer is that the number of replicas a machine can serve is dependent on multiple factors like resources, network connection, etc.
A pertinent rule is that only one replica for a given tablet can exist on a single tablet server (the replica is unique by the tablet UUID).

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: Can I think a node in yugabytedb is a machine with IP/port? Or a node can be multiple machines?

A node is a single machine/server/vps. At most, you want 1 yb-tserver & yb-master in a single server.

> Question 2: Can I think a tablet as a service running in Linux that handles read/write for the given shard?

A tablet is a shard, think like a separate rocksdb database (actually a bit more complex). It's not a separate service.

1 yb-tserver process, is multi-threaded and hosts multiple tablets/shards.

> How many tablets one machine can hold?

Tablet is the scaling unit. Each tablet can easily grow to 100GB+.

Each tablet has overhead. For a cluster with RF3, 1000 tablets have an overhead of 0.4vCPU for raft heartbeats (assuming 0.5s heartbeat interval), 300MB memory, 128GB disk-space for WAL (write-ahead log). See https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/develop/best-practices-ysql/#tablets-per-server